# Translatable rich text configuration

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a problem with translating my configuration form in Drupal 8, particularly with rich text fields.

[image]

This is my configuration file.

```
langcode: en
more_info_text: 'More info'
first_link_list:
second_link_list:
third_link_list:
```

Here is my schema file:

```
customization.config:
  type: config_object
  label: 'Website config'
  mapping:
    more_info_text:
      type: text
      label: 'More info text'
      translatable: true
    first_link_list:
      type: text_format
      label: 'First link text'
      translatable: true
      class: '\Drupal\Core\TypedData\Plugin\DataType\StringData'
    second_link_list:
      type: text_format
      label: 'Second link text'
      translatable: true
      class: '\Drupal\Core\TypedData\Plugin\DataType\StringData'
    third_link_list:
      type: text_format
      label: 'Third link text'
      translatable: true
      class: '\Drupal\Core\TypedData\Plugin\DataType\StringData'
```

The form itself works fine, but I cannot get the text format working for translations of the fields; it's always missing. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing with configs and finally found a solution. The configs should be:

```
langcode: en
more_info_text: 'More info'
first_link_list:
  format: 'full_html'
  value: ''
second_link_list:
  format: 'full_html'
  value: ''
third_link_list:
  format: 'full_html'
  value: ''
```

And the scheme file should not contain the following line

```
class: '\Drupal\Core\TypedData\Plugin\DataType\StringData'
```

Another thing I noticed is that you should translate the whole custom form, otherwise it will give an error at [config inspector](http://drupal.org/project/config_inspector), so in my case I had to split my form into general and language specific.

Hope this helps somebody